# Get request for same page but with different querystring parameters

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, postback, pageload

If we request the same page in two different tabs say `abc.aspx?id=param1` and `abc.aspx?id=param2` will the ASP.NET server treat this as request to the same page, or to two different URLs? I am using param to lookup into some DB.

I though tit would treat as same request until I stumbled into this question as I am using jQuery Idletimeout extension which communicates between multiple tabs of user for session to keep it alive or abort. But the tabs in above two pages are not synchronized and are independent. So, kind of surprised and want to check my understanding with experts here.

Pardon me if this sounds dumb. But any positive comments would help.

Thanks,

Comment: It's two different URLs.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, as already answered by Rory, server will treat it as page re-load, in other words, not as a PostBack. In order to avoid page re-loading you can implement AJAX (Microsoft AJAX) and update only the part of the page you specify. Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this is typically caused by output caching. If you add the following before doing your "work", it should resolve this dilemma.

Code:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cache.VaryByParams["*"] = true;
```

Good luck!